# Adding chart to Doc based on Spreadsheet data

Tags: google-apps-script

I'm trying to get the data from sheets, create a chart, copy the template doc and insert the chart into the copy.
My two main problems are that there are two new documents created each time and another is that instead of the chart I get the text "InlineImage".
Could anyone give me a hint where to look for an error?
Thank you in advance.

```
function openDialog() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
var docTemplate = DriveApp.getFileById('1VhkAcoPhimYpYYwf_B-VqRXXUeOhp7Wkr0zLfT17GyA');
var destinationFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById('1htUiQeikzp-wuDgq0ybNyVhceVhf_cdT');

var range = sheet.getRange("B2:K15");
var chart = sheet.newChart()
    .setChartType(Charts.ChartType.ORG)
    .addRange(range)
    .setPosition(5, 5, 0, 0)
    .build();
var row = sheet.getSheetValues(2,1,1,1);
var copy = docTemplate.makeCopy(`${row} Family Tree`, destinationFolder);
var doc = DocumentApp.openById(copy.getId());
var body = doc.getBody();
var file = body.appendImage(chart);
body.replaceText('{{NewFamilyTreeChart}}', file);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried to replicate your code and the script does not produce duplicate docs. Also,you cannot use replaceText to replace string with image. The result is "InlineImage". You should remove the text and use insertInlineImage().

Try this:

```
function createChart(){
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
  var docTemplate = DriveApp.getFileById('xxidxx');
  var destinationFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById('xxidxx');
  var range = sheet.getRange("A1:B10");
  var chart = sheet.newChart()
    .setChartType(Charts.ChartType.ORG)
    .addRange(range)
    .setPosition(5, 5, 0, 0)
    .build();
  var row = "Test";
  var copy = docTemplate.makeCopy(`${row}  Data`, destinationFolder);
  var doc = DocumentApp.openById(copy.getId());
  var body = doc.getBody();
  var text = body.findText("{{TestData}}");
  if(text){
    var r = text.getElement();
    r.asText().setText("");
    r.getParent().asParagraph().insertInlineImage(0, chart);  
  }
}
```

### Example:

**Sheets:**

[image]

**Template Doc:**

[image]

**Output:**

[image]

### References:

- [findText(searchPattern)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/text#findtextsearchpattern)
- [insertInlineImage(childIndex, image)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/paragraph?hl=en#insertinlineimagechildindex,-image)